# How accepted is ‘f***ing’ in informal conversation?

Tags: american-english, british-english, formality, offensive-language

For the past twenty years I've heard people use the adjective *"fucking"* more often than ever before in the US: in real life, in movies and on TV.  Sentences like "You *fucking* idiot."  I've also heard the word being used as an adverb. My question is: how acceptable is it in informal conversation, at work, among friends, talking to a stranger, etc. Does anyone get shocked if you use it these days?   Whatever your answer, can you say whether it applies to England and other English speaking countries?

Comment: For one, most utterers do not consider its lexical significance while using it -- it's essentially a 'filler' with no semantic contribution to the narrative. Today, its original meaning is only incidental, so much so I wonder if any American (esp., the younger lot) ever uses it in the copulatory sense at all. This is a phenomenon of language and not specific to English/ American. Other cultures may have other phrases.

Comment: Please give questions fitting, descriptive titles (what did you even mean by “something formerly considered language”?), and _please_ don't use all-caps—shouting is not polite!

Comment: It all depends . . .. Having been brought up in a non-swearing household, I personally am not comfortable with the expression in any situation, informal or otherwise. Is the use (or non-use) of the word a "moral" issue? Possibly. More to the point, the habit of swearing is a bad one, and for some people, the ability to stop at will is next to impossible. That is truly sad. Getting down and dirty with one's peers when everyone curses is OK, I guess. Just don't pollute the airwaves when people who don't curse are within earshot. It may not be a "moral" issue but it then becomes a manners issue.

Comment: @rhetorician: your personal preferences are yours, and you're quite entitled to them; but your description of the habit as "a bad one", and your use of the loaded word "pollute" are personal preferences expressed as though they were objective truths.

Comment: It is sometimes also a class issue: in the UK middle-class people tended to swear only in private, not in public; whereas working class people swore in public or private. I think the distinction is much reduced among younger people.

Comment: @ColinFine: We'll need to agree to disagree agreeably. I liken public cussing to smoking in public. Increasingly, in the US, the government is, rightly, depriving people of more and more places whey they are allowed to smoke. The deleterious effects of second-hand smoke on non-smokers is one reason for the trend. What about non-cussers' rights? Should they not be protected from second-hand cussing? While there may not be any "moral issue" (your words) involved, there is certainly an ethical issue involved, and it's called manners (decency, consideration, politeness, respect). A good friend of

Comment: mine had what is called a "conversion experience" as a young man. Before his conversion, he tells me, he and a buddy of his in the navy took a vow they would never curse again. They did this any number of times, but they weren't able to keep their vow for very long. Years later, after his conversion, my buddy tells me, "The first thing God did for me was [in my buddy's words] clean up my tongue." He attributed this phenomenon to his new-found faith. I have a feeling my buddy is neither alone nor unique in feeling relief at being freed from the cussin' habit.

Comment: @rhetorician: Yes, let's disagree agreeably. I don't swear much, and rarely in public; but I try to avoid judging people who do, and supposing that they are either depraved or vocabularily challenged. Respect and consideration are important to me, but I'm aware that politeness is a much more movable feast than some would believe. And "moral issue" was certainly not my words.

Comment: @ColinFine: Sorry, I was confused. I got the M-word from the OP. I also used the word in one of my comments. "My bad," as the young people say nowadays. Don

Comment: @ColinFine: I like your "movable feast" metaphor, but frankly I don't get it! Are you hinting that if a neighbor (or anyone in your vicinity) is cussing up a storm, that the offended party should just move (physically) out of earshot? Kind of like the old saw about if you're offended by what you're seeing on the telly, switch stations (or turn if off)?

Comment: This question would have been funnier if you had asked it the other way around. :)

Comment: @Kris You are right about most people not thinking about what it actually means when they use it. It reminds me of an exchange I heard in my schooldays and have always remembered. One girl, hoiking up her tights as they kept falling down, exclaimed, "I *hate* fucking tights!" The other answered, "Do you? I've never tried!"

Comment: The great Australian adjective used to be "bloody", but it is now "fuck".
Never used in formal or polite situations, f'ken oath!

Comment: Wow, I've a lot of weird shit about cussing, but to compare it to smoking... smoking can and will kill you (and others).  Cussing kills?

Comment: @JürgenA.Erhard  Cursing is as offensive to some people's ears, as smoking is to other people's nose.  That's the analogy. No health implications.

Comment: I quote @rheto: _deleterious effects of second-hand smoke on non-smokers_  I took it to be a reference to health issues.  Which is a valid reason for restricting smoking rights.

Comment: @JürgenA.Erhard  You're right. It was about health issues. I missed that.

Comment: The last edit negates the accepted answer almost entirely. It had good advice, now it's just someone's opinion.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Swearing in a foreign language is very rarely a good idea.  As well as the difficulty of judging the level of acceptability of swearing in what will by definition be an unfamiliar social situation, there is the difficulty of judging any particular word (the French *con* is a very mild insult while the English equivalent is one of the strongest known- in Britain, though not necessarily elsewhere). A slight misjudgment in swearing less than your companions will hardly be noticed, while a misjudgment in the other direction could have dire social consequences.  And there are usually witty ways to avoid the necessity; Evelyn Waugh, faced with the need to reproduce soldiers' conversation in a novel that had to get past the censor, wrote 'Their language was shocking. "Shock me", they said "if that shocker gives a shock for any shocker that ever shocked. I'll be shocked if he does."'

Comment: This is the right answer.  I would add that, in the US, there is huge variability in the acceptability of swearing from one subgroup to the next.  People of different ages, genders, races, levels of religious commitment (especially!) and personal temperaments will all react very differently to the same coarse usage.

Answer (score 6):

> How morally acceptable is (it) in informal conversation at work

Only if one works for a f****** idiot who swears like a sailor.

> among friends

Unfortunately quite common in youth, decreasing in frequency with age, gender, and often with educational level.

> talking to a stranger

Never, unless one is, well, an idiot.

> etc.

Depends. One hears it often when people are stressed or intoxicated. In the Emergency Room, we hear it often, and refer the condition as *an acute adjective deficiency*.

> Does anyone get shocked if you use it?

Yes. I am not a prude, but it always shocks me in person. I've become more accustomed to it in movies of certain genres. On television, most cable channels limit the word to once per season, even in *Breaking Bad*, a fantastic show about a high school chemistry teacher turned meth cooker.

> can you say whether it applies to England?

From what I've heard in England, it's just as bad or worse than in the US.

Comment: In _The Wire_, another good series, they had trouble limiting the word to only once per utterance! It has become more ubiquitous in England, even in supposedly higher-brow newspapers such as _The Guardian_. And like you, I find the word still has great power to shock. I would advise non-native speakers to avoid the word, since, for me at least, it comes across as being forced and occasionally completely risible.

Comment: Although I have only a very limited set of data to draw from, I would say that actually being shocked at hearing someone use the word is becoming relatively rare. Personally, I use it sparingly, but it doesn’t shock me in the slightest to hear it—but then I think I still count as being in the younger generation. I do tend to notice it when it’s used in an unexpected situation, such as when my professor (who’s from Michigan, if I recall correctly) uses it during class.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - **!**

Comment: @Susan, was that shock at me not being shocked at all, or at my professor using the word in class? (I should mention that he’s only 26, so quite young to be teaching in university—and that our classes are very informal settings, just a teacher/professor and about five students in a fairly small room. So less incentive to stick to formalities than in bigger, less personal settings.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - the professor! Wow!

Comment: This is not something that would be expected, even here. We have a _very_ unique atmosphere and student-teacher relationship in general, so don’t make too much of it. :-)

Comment: From all the answers and comments I got, I conclude that the f*** word is perfectly acceptable by those who use it, and offensive to those who don't.  Simple as that.  As you can't tell who's who at first sight, better not to use it until you can.  In my case, I hardly swear, even in my mother tongue.

Comment: @Luis: I think that would be an erroneous conclusion. I myself am capable of swearing profusely and fluently, *if I feel like it, and if the context seems "suitable" to me*. Some people rarely or never swear, and it's often (but not *always*) desirable to avoid or limit one's swearing in their company. But the fact that I personally sometimes swear a lot certainly doesn't imply I'm never offended by other people swearing in my presence (whether or not they are aware of my own usage patterns).

Comment: @FumbleFingers,

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think you've missed my point. My conclusion applies to the use of the "f word" as a filler in ordinary conversation, and not to swearing.  I, myself, use language at specific situations (e.g. If my car gets bumped, If, after waiting two hours at the airport, I'm told my flight has been cancelled, that kind of incident)  And I find it perfectly acceptable to hear someone swear in similar circumstances. Rather, I'd find abnormal the person who doesn't utter a single swear word when a bird drops his wastes on his head or clean white shirt. I never use these, fillers though,

Comment: @Luis: I don't understand your apparent distinction between *use of the "f word" as a filler in ordinary conversation* on the one hand, and *swearing* on the other. To me, "fillers" are things like "Um", "Ah", "Well", "Yunno", etc. Very rarely, "fuck" may fill something *like* that role (perhaps in non-committal *"Fuck, I dunno!"*, for example). But usually it's an actual word, with at least *some* specific grammatical role and semantic significance.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The distinction is the following:as a filler, you use it as an adjective or adverb, in almost every sentence, and not because you are angry or disappointed. In the US there are a lot of people who use it all the time and, as someone pointed above, it doesn't mean anything at all.  QUOTE: For one, most utterers do not consider its lexical significance while using it -- it's essentially a 'filler' with no semantic contribution. Today, its original meaning is only incidental, so much so I wonder if any American (the younger lot) ever uses it in the copulatory sense at all. UNQUOTE.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  People use these words as interjections, adjectives and even adverbs.  For some, it's a habit deeply rooted in their brains.   Swearing is different, you have a reason to use a word which is not part of your usual vocabular but comes to mind when an unexpected and/or harmful event happens to you.

Comment: @Luis: oic. Well, by that definition I suppose I'd have to say that although *in some contexts* I use a lot of "swear words", I probably almost never actually "swear". It's extremely unusual for me to "accidentally" swear simply because of something unexpected/painful happening. My choice of register is primarily dictated by how I expect my words to be received, not my own internal state. Obviously if I'm extremely agitated, for example, I might well swear simply because it's an easy way to forcefully convey that - but probably *not*, if I thought it would trigger other "unwanted" reactions).

Comment: @FumbleFingers  "My choice of register is primarily dictated by how I expect my words to be received, not my own internal state."  So is mine and every civilized human being's. However, at those rare moments when something unexpected and painful has just happened, there is nothing better to a "Latin Mentality" than shout out/say/whisper, a very strong word.

Comment: Wow, didn't know gender increased... and you're wrong, your personal bias is showing, strongly.  Google "fry on swearing" about swearing and level of education.

Answer (score 2):

I can only speak for the UK, where this word, and another considered somewhat stronger, are commonly used in normal speech, although in certain company, effort is usually made to restrain the use of these words. The sort of company where you try not to use them might be amongst elderly people, certainly children and when with persons you know to be of a 'polite' mindset and who would find it offensive. Nor would you use these expressions at, say, a formal dinner, so in old fashioned terms, never in 'polite company'. I never use them in front of my now elderly mother-in-law, but otherwise, in most company, mine and most everyone else's speech is peppered with this expression, to the point where it's just a word without any real shock value. Whether you use it at work  or not depends on the workplace - in some places it's fine, but possibly not when the boss is around, it varies.

I guess I should add that I live in London - there may be regional differences regarding the use of this word.

As for the word being used in its original sense/meaning, yes, it is used for that as well, over here anyway.

Comment: There's a *stronger* word?! I can't imagine what it is.

Comment: @Susan, perhaps a simple maternal prefix does the trick?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - ah. One hears it here, but not enough to have it come to mind. *That* is still really very shocking.

Comment: As Bamboo is speaking about the UK, I suspect he is thinking of the c*** word!

Comment: @Shoe - I cannot imagine that word being used often. It... is really shocking, and thankfully still rare here.

Comment: @Shoe: SHE is indeed thinking about see you next tuesday, though its use is not quite as often as the f word. I used to be really shocked by it, but you get used to anything if you're exposed often enough. What's interesting is that other words are infinitely more shocking, such as the 'n' word which is almost never heard unless spoken by a black person here.

Comment: Even I find ‘cunt’ quite appallingly bad taste (and by extension find it atrociously ugly as a word, too) and do not make a habit of using it. Oddly, I have absolutely no such qualms with the, for all intents and purposes, fully comparable ‘twat’, which I'll gladly use quite unabashedly (in the right setting, naturally—although yet again I have to admit that I have used it in the classroom of the same professor I mentioned above).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: dear oh dear, there am I balking at putting the word in print and you go and do it, lol... I rarely use it, but my feminist principles ensure that when I do, it is exclusively in reference to males or male behaviour. Twat isn't used much here now, but I do hear it as 'twatted' meaning you've clipped someone round the ear - seems to be a substitute for 'swatted'.

Comment: @Susan The c-word can be used in the UK with less offence than in the US. In some social settings, it has similar strength to words like "dick", "knob", "wanker", etc. Just a general insult that doesn't mean anything. As always, it's context that offends (or doesn't). There are plenty of British people who would still find it extremely offensive (but maybe not so many as, say, 10 years ago).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet "Motherfucker" is rarely used here in the UK.

Comment: @starsplusplus agree with both your comments and would add that, compared with all the rest, I find motherfucker very offensive and irritating indeed, and I'm finding it crops up more often over here, unfortunately. After all, in its widest literal meaning, it's not exactly uncommon behaviour since many females are mothers, and in terms of offensiveness, its such a childish and 'macho' thing to say

Comment: @bamboo Is the word "bloody", used in the U.K. as an adjective, just as strong and offensive as the "f*ing" word ?  Do they convey exactly the same ?

Comment: @Luis No, "bloody" is milder. It's more like "damn" than "fucking". We also have "sodding" which is similar to "bloody". But apart from strength the meaning is the same: annoying, offensive, frustrating, etc.

Comment: @bamboo Yes, and you could say the same about "cocksucker". Literally, why should that be offensive? But it is.

Comment: @starsplusplus Agree with comment on 'bloody' - 'bleedin's' (old London expression) not been mentioned, though you don't hear that much any more, far too mild for today's climate. Funny enough, I don't find cocksucker as offensive, probably because it doesn't denote male or female necessarily, but again, a piece of macho nonsense.